# C++ struct memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory, struct

in C++ if I define a structure like this

```
struct ComplexFloat {
  float r;
  float i;
};
```

and I declare two variables like this

```
struct ComplexFloat cf;
float *f=(float*)cf;
```

can I safely assume that the following condition will always be true

```
(&(cf.r)==&(f[0]) && &(cf.i)==&(f[1]))
```

?

In other words, can I safely assume that in a struct containing floats, its elements will occupy contiguous positions in memory and will be ordered according to the order in which they appear in the definition of the struct?

I tested and it is the case with gcc 4.8.2 on Ubuntu, I just want to make sure it is always valid.

Comment: That expression won't even compile, `cf` is not an array or a pointer.

Comment: If this is for academic curiosity, it's fine but if it is for production code, you might want to rethink your design.

Comment: thanks @JoachimPileborg, I corrected the question

Comment: Also, this will violate the [strict aliasing rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot assume that i will be in the right place unless you control the alignment of data in the struct. There might be alignment padding between r and i

Comment: They must be in the same order though